# Contradiction between ROC curve and randomization test

Tags: classification, p-value, roc

I'm building a classifier and I want to prove that it performs better than the level of chance. So, I shuffled the labels and I performed a randomization test. The p-value I got was ~.3 . On the other hand, When I plotted the ROC curve, the area was .61. Is there a contradiction here?

Comment: What's the p value for your AUROC? that value could be insignificant at lowish sample numbers.

Comment: @ReneBt how to compute the p-value for the ROC? I mean it doesn't change over different runs, does it?

Comment: When I want a quick check I use http://vassarstats.net/roc_comp.html, with the AUC for the second group set to 0.5. The ROC, and associated metrics, are empirical measures of your data, so will change with your data in different runs.

Comment: What p-value? What test?

Answer (score 0):

There is no contradiction in what you have written so far. P values are partly dependent on sample size, area under the curve is not. So, for some sample size, you will get p of 0.3 for any particular effect size.

Comment: Which one is more accurate you think?

Comment: Since they measure different things, you can't really compare their accuracy.

Comment: I believe that when I was shuffling the labels, some of the labels would have the correct position. In other words, the shuffled datasets are not completely random, they are biased and have some information about the problem. So, I need to shuffle the features in addition to the label. I think this is an interpretation of what that's happening. Do you agree?

Comment: This doesn't make sense. If you shuffled them randomly, they are random. If you didn't shuffle them randomly, then shuffle them again and do it randomly.